# No implicit conversion of Struct into Array

Tags: arrays, ruby, implicit-conversion

I had an occurrence where I was working with an array of structs and wanted to [`transpose`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/transpose) them, though was met with an error:

> `TypeError (no implicit conversion of Struct into Array)`

I'd thought (incorrectly) that such implicit conversion simply called `to_a` on each object if available, though structs do have a [`to_a` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Struct.html#method-i-to_a).

So my question is two part:

- if I can, how do I implement this implicit conversion?
- secondly, *why* is this the case? Why can't structs be implicitly converted to arrays, yet can be explicitly converted?

Here's a minimal example to produce the error:

```
S = Struct.new(:a, :b)

a = S.new(1, 2)
# => #<struct S a=1, b=2>
b = S.new(3, 4)
# => #<struct S a=3, b=4>

[a, b].transpose
# TypeError (no implicit conversion of S into Array)

[a, b].map(&:to_a)
# => [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

# Therefore, the extra step I'd have to take to transpose:
[a, b].map(&:to_a).transpose
# => [[1, 3], [2, 4]]
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually found the answer to this while researching the question, so will pop the answer in as I couldn't find anything similar when searching earlier.

Ruby uses different coercion methods for explicit vs implicit conversion:

```
| Explicit | Implicit |
|----------|----------|
| to_i     | to_int   |
| to_s     | to_str   |
| to_a     | to_ary   | 
| to_h     | to_hash  |
|----------|----------|
```

So the problem here is structs don't have a `to_ary` method:

```
a.to_ary
# NoMethodError (undefined method `to_ary' for #<struct S a=1, b=2>)
```

Therefore, if we define this method on the struct in question, we can implicitly convert:

```
S.define_method(:to_ary) do
  self.to_a
end

[a, b].transpose
# => [[1, 3], [2, 4]]
```

Voila :)

Answer (score 1):

> if I can, how do I implement this implicit conversion?

You can pass a block to `Struct.new` and then define your method there:

```rb
S = Struct.new(:a, :b) do
  alias_method :to_ary, :to_a
end
```

> secondly, why is this the case? Why can't structs be implicitly converted to arrays, yet can be explicitly converted?

This is somewhat philosophical, but `to_ary`, `to_int`, etc. indicate that those objects really represent an array, integer, etc. respectively; they're just not exactly the right type.

It's different for the one letter variants of `to_a`, `to_i`, which indicate that the object could fall in for an array, integer, etc. but their underlying structure is quite different, or only represents a portion of their true semantics.